# Removing node from xml doc in vb

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

i am using vb , and i am loading the xml in this way

```
 xml_doc.LoadXml(contents)
```

Well now i want to remove a node from this loaded xml or from content(this holds the whole xml), i am not sure from where it needs to be.
The xml is like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<sdnList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd">
  <publshInformation>
    <Publish_Date>07/21/2016</Publish_Date>
    <Record_Count>5393</Record_Count>
  </publshInformation>
  <sdnEntry>
    <uid>36</uid>
  </sdnEntry>
</sdnList>
```

What i want to do is to remove this tag and all inside

```
<publshInformation>......</publshInformation>
```

Comment: Could you solve the problem with my answer as it does not need LINQ?

Comment: yes your answer helped me thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remove it like so

```
Dim nodeToRemove as XmlNode = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='publshInformation']")
nodeToRemove.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToRemove)
```

Note: I used `local-name()` in the XPath to ignore the XML namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim publshInformation As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "publshInformation").FirstOrDefault()
        publshInformation.Remove()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: i am on older version, coz this is big old project(vs2003), cant use Linq